# how do i arrange flex items with different dimensions in my container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: This is a sketch of what I'm trying to achieve]

I want to achieve the above design with flexbox, but I don't know how; does anyone know a solution?

I've attached my HTML, and a sketch of it.

```html
<ul class="blogPosts">
  <div class="blogPost1">
    <li>
      <img src="assets/image-2.jpg" alt="">
      <h3>Blog Post 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum!</p>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="blogPost2">
    <li>
      <img src="assets/image-3.jpg" alt="">
      <h3>Blog Post 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="blogPost4">
    <li>
      <img src="assets/image-5.jpg" alt="">
      <h3>Blog Post 4 </h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="blogPost3">
    <li>
      <img src="assets/image-4.jpg" alt="">
      <h3>Blog Post 3: About Me!</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum!</p>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Hopefully I can get this resolved. Your guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<ul>` can contain `<li>` children only.

Comment: oh i didnt know this. i will update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want to do it using grid, no problem. You can also use flex-box for that,
However, this will be a little too much code to do so.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem; 
  height: 25rem;
  width: 25rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: pink;
}

.top-sub-container {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.sub-container {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sub-container">
        <div class="top-sub-container">
            <div class="box box-1">
                <img src="yourChoice.png" />
                <div class="box-text">
                    This is the text of the box 1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box box-2">
                <img src="yourChoice.png" />
                <div class="box-text">
                    This is the text of the box 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box box-3">
            <img src="yourChoice.png" />
            <div class="box-text">
                This is the text of the box 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box box-4">
        <img src="yourChoice.png" />
        <div class="box-text">
            This is the text of the box 4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh my gosh. thank you so much! ahmad, do you have any flexbox resources i can refer to in the future? how do you plan this out? i'm on week 3 of learning flexbox and i find it quite challenging.

Comment: The best resource i know for flex-box is a video on Youtube... [Here](https://youtu.be/fYq5PXgSsbE) is the link for that... If my answer solved your problem, Kindly give it a green check

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for Grid, not Flexbox

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid

Something like this (on the container) should be a solid start.

```
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
```

Comment: im unfortunately not allowed to use grid for this